# ImageView setScale applied, wrong alignment in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, scale

I have a large image to be placed on parent's left Center. This is straight forward, and looks like that:

[Large picture with layout_alignParentRight & layout_centerVertical true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGYHV.png)

It is too big, so I applied this, to make it smaller:

```
rightButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
rightButton.setScaleX(0.5f);
rightButton.setScaleY(0.5f);
```

But now it looks like that:

[Scaled image, but not properly aligned to parents right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiHJ9.png)

Questions:

1. Is setSaceX & Y a proper way to resize image?
2. I understnad that original image is still there, filling rest of space. Any way to move scaled image to the right? Tried setPivotX & setPivotY but without luck

Comment: I don't think you can do this purely with ImageView.  You'll probably have to make a layout to position a smaller ImageView the way you want relative to the parent.

Comment: You do not provide your xml, but try setting `adjustViewBounds="true"` on your image view

Comment: @DavidMedenjak unfortunetely no effect.